# Android Studio: How to add dependencies from gradle caches

Tags: android, android-studio, jcenter

My android project implements some dependencies from JCenter, problem is now JCenter has shutting down and i my project can't start.
I have copied gradle caches folder of libraries. How can i use it in my computer and in my team computer?
Thanks

- Android Studio: Arctic Fox:2020.3.1
- Gragle version: 7.0.0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i resolve my problem by using mavenLocal()
I copy all file into folder /Users/***/.m2/repository/io/wl-core/core/0.0.188
[image]

Note: starting from gradle 7.0.0, if i declare **<s>jcenter()</s>** and https://dl.bintray.com/* in repositories, gradle will not sync or throw error. Use lower version, project run normally